# POST Json data using Java script

Tags: java, javascript, json

I have a Java snippet code already implemented as follows:

```
          //some logic above

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

            try {

                    json.put("name", "myname");

                    json.put("address","myaddress");


                  List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                  nameValuePairs = Utils.addEmpName(nameValuePairs);

                  nameValuePairs = Utils.addEmpAddress(nameValuePairs);


                  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(

                            "myjsondata",

                            jsondata.toString());

                  ....

               httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
           }
```

It does a POST request to my server and sends the JSON data.

My question is how do I perform the same in Javascript. I know how to construct the JSON data but as far as `nameValuePairs` are concerned, can anyone tell me how to send them as my JSON body via javascript?

My Javascript code looks like this at present in Javascript

```
var data= { "name":"myname", "address" : "myaddress" };            
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("POST",my_url,true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

I need help in writing the `nameValuePairs` part in order to construct json body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost any modern JavaScript framework like jQuery or prototype has very simple methods to send/receive json(-like) objects to/from a server

UPDATE:

jQuery:

```
var d = { "aa":"bbbbb", "xxx":"yyyy" };
$.ajax({ 
  url:'http:yourserver.com/your_action',
  data:d
});
```

Prototype:

```
var d = { "aa":"bbbbb", "xxx":"yyyy" };
new Ajax.Request( 'http:yourserver.com/your_action', { parameters:d } );
```

Your can customize what to do on successful send, on failure etc. see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Request/

Comment: can u give an example?

Comment: Yes got that but how to send namevaluepairs..see my Java code above..i Have to send `EmpName` and 'EmpAddress` also. That too as URL encoded entity. Please tell me how to do that

Comment: not sure what you exactly mean by that... `var d = { "EmpName":"EmpName value", "EmpAddress":"EmpAddress value" };` might do

Answer (score 0):

You should use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) instead of manually handling XHR requests.

You can either use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) functions.

```
$.post( my_url, { "name":"myname", "address" : "myaddress" });
```

**Edited:** To pass custom HTTP headers, use $.ajax() instead of $.post(). Although the header you are referencing to use standard header and JQuery should detect and automatically add this to above request. Anyway, you can use following code snippet to achieve the same using $.ajax().

```
$.ajax({
    url: my_url,
    type: 'post',
    data: { "name":"myname", "address" : "myaddress" },
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.info(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: yes that's fine. My question is how do I send nameValuePairs as json body via javascript..My request requires me to send headers and json data along with namevaluepairs

Comment: I am familiar with the java code..I need some help forming the javascript code since I can't use java

Comment: You can pass custom HTTP headers in JQuery ajax function.

Comment: how to send namevaluepairs..see my Java code above..i Have to send `EmpName` and 'EmpAddress` also. That too as URL encoded entity. Please tell me how to do that