# How to make a constrained file transfer with java servlets

Tags: java, servlets, upload

I need to transfer some binary files form a generic java client to my server that uses the servlet technology.
The problem comes since I need to check some data sent me with the file in order to authorize the upload. Furthermore I'll need also additional information about the file in order to characterize it (name, author,...) .

What I though is:

- (A) use a GenericServlet that receives the request through the default inputstream. It will read a pre-formatted data structure and then if data are ok it will read and save the file
- (B) Use an HttpServlet and make the usual http file upload (this will require an http support in the client environment) and use some post attributes in order to get the additional data.

now questions:
option A:

- is There a way to get the initial data before the file in order to first chek them and then allow the file transfer only if data are ok in such a way to limit the memory usage in cases in which data are not ok?
- If files are long and arrive to the server in let's say N parts, and the servlet checks the additional info finding that they're not good before the client finishes to send all the N parts, is there a way to break the transfer by answering to the client during the transfer in such a way to break a "bad" and heavy request?
- Can I transfer multiple Java Objects (like in this case custom FileInfo class) together with binary files in the same request?

option B:

- is it a good pratice to always use http?
- once set the multipart datatype, the file content is sent as the content of a post variable?

thanks

Comment: You can check filesize client-side in Javascript before beginning the upload https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation For the rest, I'd be surprised if it were possible.

Comment: Clients does not suppose to be html / js in general. Anyway i prefer to validate data serverside cause its safer and i need to check and store more data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options are good but B is more flexible than A. I just implemented option B at work to replace/hide a legacy protocol. In my opinion it is good practice to use HTTP: it will not go away anytime soon and almost any programming language has good support for it. Plus administrators have lots of tools for it to authorize request, direct traffic and monitor load.

I've choosen the following setup:

Client does a two-part post using Apache's [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) and HttpMime (see for a multi-part post example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21762955/3080094)). First part is a JSON (UTF-8) string containing all required meta-data. This JSON string is encoded/decoded via a Map<String, Object>, example using Jackson is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21812146/3080094). Second part is a file-upload (FileBody-part).

The server is a Tomcat Servlet that receives both parts using Commons [FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/). The first JSON part is expected first and validated. If it is not OK, the servlet immediatly sends a "NOK" response (e.g. "Bad request"). Then the file is received and processed.

I've choosen JSON for meta-data because that is a format that is easy to understand (readable like XML) and has good support in the [web-world](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21351520/3080094). Alternative is to use the http-headers for parameters and send the file as body (probably easier to implement).

I've choosen Apache's HttpMime and Common's FileUpload because they work really well together. It's not hard to understand how these should work together (study the examples) and I have yet to encounter a problem that was really difficult to solve. Also, Apache's HttpClient 4.3 finally supports functions by default (e.g. (de)compressing of requests) where I previously had to jump to hoops.

But number one for me: the processing of the file-data is done STREAMING. I've confirmed this by uploading a 2GB file in a multi-part post request that was compressed on the fly by Apache HttpClient. Neither client nor server claimed any extra memory to process this large file (but it does take some time to transfer all the bytes ofcourse).

Due to the nature of HTTP I fear you cannot make the client stop sending file-data once it has started. But this should not be a problem as this would be an exceptional situation, not the norm.

Comment: thank you very much for the suggestions, I will check the httpmime and fileupload solution!

Comment: Another question, how do you mean with 2-part request? Two requests or a single request divided in two parts?

Comment: @mb_ The latter (see the multi-part post example). The first (two requests) would be a lot slower due to network latency. Also, since HTTP is stateless in nature, how would the server keep track of two separate client requests that are related?

Comment: using sessions? by the way it is what i was thinking. Thanks for the replies I'm studying apache http components right now!